# scalaz Zero defined in base class

Tags: scala, types, scalaz

I'm just getting started with Scalaz. I'm trying to define a Zero for my type in its superclass.

```
class Base { 
  implicit def BaseZ: Zero[this.type] = zero(classOf[this.type].newInstance() )
}

class Child extends Base

~Option(null:Child) //trying to make this produce: new Child
```

I'm getting two errors:

1) As is, this produces `"error: class type required but Base.this.type found"`

2) If I change the second occurrence of this.type to Base (which isn't useful), I get

> type mismatch;
>      found   : Base
>      required: Base.this.type

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong with this.type here? I really don't want to have to pass or override a type parameter to Base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.type` is not the same as the type of this class. `this.type` is the singleton type of this particular instance. In other words, the following will not work:

```
scala> class X { def x:this.type=new X }
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : X
 required: X.this.type
       class X { def x:this.type=new X }
```

On the other hand, this will:

```
scala> class X { def x:this.type=this }
defined class X
```

As of the Zeros, I'd create a companion object and put each zero in it.

Comment: So is there no way to say that the zero of each Child that extends Base should produce a new Child?